# Django Invalid JSON Response

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-views

The following code produces the JSON given below.  But when I validate it from JSON lint, it is invalid. What am I doing wrong here?

```
  def json_candidate_get(request, model, m_id=None):
     response = {'message' : 'Incorrect Json'}
     try:

        obj = model.objects.filter(pk=m_id)
        ce = Candidate_profiles.objects.filter(pk=m_id)
        cw = Candidate_company_profiles.objects.filter(pk=m_id)
        response = json.dumps({  'TechnologiesValue':[],'Technologies': []  })
      except Exception as e:
        logging.exception("Exception"+str(e))
     return response



  @is_login()
  def candidate_create(request,m_id=None,token=None):
     response_data = {'message': 'unsuccessfull'}
     if token is not None:
        try:
           if request.method == 'GET':
              response_data = json_candidate_get(request,Candidates,m_id)
              print response_data
              #response_data = serializers.serialize('json', response_data)
        except Exception as e:
           logging.exception(e)

     return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="application/json")
```

JSON:

```
{
TechnologiesValue: [0]
Technologies: [0]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `json.dumps` function is meant to convert certain Python objects to a a JSON string.  But you are already serializing your model instances (via QuerySets) to JSON strings, and `json.dumps` is trying to convert these strings into JSON all over again--it only knows that you've passed it `str` objects, not that these `str` objects represents JSON.

The JSON encoder used by `json.dumps` only knows how to convert a handful of built-in types:

- [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#py-to-json-table)
- [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table)

So what you need to do is convert your model instances to one of these types.  The easiest solution would be to use [`django.forms.models.model_to_dict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/forms/models/) on each element of your QuerySets, like so:

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
response = json.dumps({
   'candidate': [model_to_dict(x) for x in obj],
   'CandidateEducationProfile': [model_to_dict(x) for x in ce],
   ...
)
```

Comment: >>> r=json.dumps({'ce' : model_to_dict(ce),'cw': model_to_dict(cw)})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 130, in model_to_dict
    opts = instance._meta
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that these are `QuerySet`s rather than model instances.  You'll need to apply model_to_dict to each object in the QuerySet, e.g. `{'candidates': [model_to_dict(x) for x in list(obj)], 'CandidateEducationProfiles': [model_to_dict(x) for x in list(ce)], ...}`.